# How to fix ambari-server.service failed

Tags: command-line, server

[ambari-server.service failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEq5e.png)

[after use journalctl -xe command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTEAu.png)

Comment: Please edit your questions and put some efforts in describing your problem in word plus copy & paste the relevant parts of the error log into you post. Just posting two pictures is a bit too lazy.